# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Disable Server Cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there anyway to disable cache on a action of a returned view? By using an attribute or something? The reason for this is that IE9 and below seem to always cache my views/partial views, so I'd like to prevent that for some actions

Comment: Do you mean browser cache or server cache?

Comment: Both! I think i've done it with browser cache using JQuery, but Server cache is what I want to disable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting this attribute on an action should do the trick:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

Comment: It tells me that duration must be a positive number, so should I just set it to 1? Cache of 1 second should be fine i think?

Comment: +1 I edited the post, NoStore instead of VaryByParam. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: 0 means that no cache should be used.

Comment: @jgauffin Not all! I've used `[OutputCache(Duration=0, VaryByParam="None"]` in the past and it worked for me, but after reading the MSDN docs, your solution actually makes more sense.

Comment: This doesnt work: System.InvalidOperationException: Duration must be a positive number. So I've set Duration = 1, 1 second shouldnt cause any harm

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: Strange. I've always used `0`.

Comment: My mistake, this does work, I was using [OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")] I changed it to your answer and it works! Thanks. Just another Question: If I apply this to a parent view, is there a need for me to apply it to child actions?